# Given two random integer arrays, print their intersection. That is, print all the elements that are present in both the given arrays

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class temp_2 {

    public static void intersection(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){

        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        Arrays.sort(arr2);
        int i=0;
        int j=0;

        while((i != arr1.length) || (j != arr2.length)){

            if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]){
                System.out.println(arr1[i]);
                i++;
                j++;

            }
            else{
                if(arr1[i]<arr2[j])
                    i++;
                else if(arr1[i]>arr2[j])
                    j++;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
int[] a={1,2,3,3};
int[] b={2,2,3,4,5};
        intersection(a,b);
    }

}
```

// it prints right answer but then it gives an error of java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Where did i went wrong?
I first sorted both arrays and then used this method to print if equal or to increment index unless its end of either array.

Comment: `(i != arr1.length) || (j != arr2.length)` —Because you're using `||`, you allow the loop to continue when one of your variables has passed the end of the array and the other has not.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your statement from:

```
 (i != arr1.length) || (j != arr2.length)
```

To:

```
(i < arr1.length) && (j < arr2.length)
```

Consider using retainAll method from List interface:

```
retainAll(Collection<?> c)
```

Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

Answer (score 0):

public class CommonElementsInArray {

```
public static void main(String a[]){
    int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] arr2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,9};
    for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
            if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]){
                System.out.println(arr1[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Output : 1,2,3,4,5

Hope this helps!